# Right to left language support in php

Tags: php, arabic, right-to-left

I am developing a site where people will put their comments, in arabic. my website is built in php. does any body know a way how to add right-to- left language support to write text in english?

Answer (score 12):

Try specifying `<html dir="rtl">` in your markup.

I would read: http://www.w3.org/International/tutorials/bidi-xhtml/

If for some reason you need left to right on a certain element, just specify the dir attribute on it: `<div dir="ltr"></div>`

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem obtained even I try rtl in textarea where from I was sending my arabic data into database finally it solved when I also apply rtl at the div where I was calling data to print at that div. So use rtl at both sides one where data is sending into database and second where data is retrieving to print.

Answer (score 0):

Add Before Php Tag body{  direction: rtl;}