# How to split a right-to-left string in php

Tags: php, right-to-left

In my php code I need to split an arabic string. However when I copy the string it writes in left to right direction and split function splits the string reversly. Is there a way in php to say that make the string in rtl direction so that it splits correctly?

```
$text="انا احمد.";

$mysplit = mb_split(' ',$text);
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=php+rtl => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077895/right-to-left-language-support-in-php also check http://php.net/manual/en/function.hebrev.php

Comment: this is not what I asked about.

Comment: What you getting currently & what output you are expecting ?

Comment: Ok, sorry about that. I don't know about a PHP core function to do that. However, you may use `$mysplit = array_reverse($mysplit); `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though your question is bit vague. Seems that [array_reverse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) is what you are looking for.

```
$text="انا احمد.";
$mysplit = mb_split(' ',$text);
$mysplit = array_reverse($mysplit);
```

[CodeViper Demo.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Ak75Y2)

Answer (score 2):

Actually adding `\u200e` in front of the string, marks it as left to right.
So then you might be able to split it without needing to reverse the array.

For Right to Left marking the character is `\u200f`

Comment: left to right or right to left? I want it to be in rtl direction.

Comment: left to right: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm I have edited my answer and provided right to left marking too