# Brackets get flipped around

Tags: php, utf-8

I'm using UTF-8 in PHP for Hebrew, and I want to detect if a bracket is being used at the end of a word, like this: [נסיון. Note: Hebrew is a right-to-left language.

The data is coming in from user form input, and I'm accessing the data with the `$_POST["input"]` variable.

When I output the variable instead of the bracket wrapping the word, it's facing the opposite direction. This glitch is making my code act other than I expect.

I've encoded everything for UFT-8 all throughout, and otherwise, everything seems to be working just perfectly. Does anyone have a solution/workaround for this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Right to left language support in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077895/right-to-left-language-support-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `<html dir="rtl">` in your markup.

I would read: http://www.w3.org/International/tutorials/bidi-xhtml/

If for some reason you need left to right on a certain element, just specify the dir attribute on it: `<div dir="ptr"></div>`

This is a duplicate.

See here: [Right to left language support in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077895/right-to-left-language-support-in-php)

Comment: I have that already. This is the code for the form:'<html>
<body>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="text" dir="rtl" name="input">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>'

Comment: The issue starts way before the meat of my code. I can produce this issue by just echoing $_POST["input"]. We don't need the entire code. As far as everything else, I'm UTF-8 encoded and that's working fine.

Comment: Try using <html dir="rtl"> and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Awesome. Glad I could be of help. Please mark as the correct answer.